# Painfully slow regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm trying to parse a formatted email that looks something like this:

```
From: Mr. Bob Simon Jones
Email: moo@cows.com
Comments: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris hendrerit, nibh a  tristique malesuada, tellus nibh pharetra mauris, id tincidunt lacus turpis vel risus. 
Vestibulum laoreet venenatis mauris sit amet suscipit. Cras vel pharetra nisl. Suspendisse venenatis ante quis tellus luctus id ornare sem pretium. Cras sodales tristique mauris sagittis ullamcorper. 
Ut sit amet urna magna. Nullam et odio sit amet mauris tempus egestas. Donec eget risus nec lectus adipiscing convallis. Pellentesque in velit enim. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi quis ante diam. Etiam rhoncus leo vulputate ligula luctus volutpat. Praesent luctus, justo eget auctor viverra, diam turpis fringilla elit, non commodo massa arcu et eros. Cras elementum faucibus elit, sollicitudin luctus mi dictum a.
Address: First line, Second Line, Third line pe2 8pd, Fourth Line
Date of Visit: 25/06/2011
```

I've got a regular expression which works if that's the only text present, but when theres a load of junk text after it goes stupidly slow, when running in a .NET app it doesn't seem to complete at all.

The regular expression is:

```
.*From: (?<title>Mrs\.|Mr\.|Miss\.|Ms\.) (?<firstName>(\w| )*)(?<=. )(?<surname>(\w| )*)\s*
Email: (?<email>.*)\s*
Comments: (?<comments>(.|\s)*)\s*
Address: (?<address1>[^,]*), (?<address2>[^,]*), (?<address3>[^,]*),(?<address4>.*)\s*
Date of Visit: (?<dateOfVisit>\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d).*
```

The first line finds every name bar the final one and uses that as the first name and the last name as the surname.

I assume its probably got something to do with this:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

But I can't quite figure it out. Wondering if anyone might be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Any particular reason you're using RegEx as opposed to regular string manipulation?

Comment: +1 - that is a really good example to show how regexps should not be designed.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when you are building a regex, focus on what YOU want not fluff out there. You are interested in the "From: etc.." (what YOU want) your regex would be "From: .*"; no need to use ".*" (fluff) before !

Comment: There may be unwanted text before and after the actual required fields, I just didn't include it above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some enhancements to regex, can you test it out ?

```
From: (?<title>(?:Mrs|Mr|Miss|Ms)\.) (?<firstName>[\w ]*)(?<=. )(?<surname>[\w ]*)\s*
Email: (?<email>.*)\s*
Comments: (?<comments>(.*))\s*
Address: (?<address1>[^,]*), (?<address2>[^,]*), (?<address3>[^,]*),(?<address4>.*)\s*
Date of Visit: (?<dateOfVisit>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})
```

Use it with **single line** option

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I haven't had a chance to test this yet, will be able to tomorrow

Answer (score 6):

Yikes. You're trying to do way too much at once. Break it up into smaller pieces:

1. First, get the raw value of each field. For example, everything that falls between `From:` and `Email:` is the name. Don't try to be clever - be blind. The contents of name aren't important yet - just the blob.
2. Treat each value separately and process it independently as a distinct value with its own rules. Some might be dates, some might be names with a title, etc. You can write a small, simpler regex to suss out this more particular data into a format that makes sense.

Comment: +1. Would vote this up twice if I could. Everytime I see people creating such regular expressions, I feel some pain in my stomach and think by myself "did they never learn to keep things simple"?

Comment: @Doc Brown This regexp seems painful because there is many named captures and many repetitions; nothing more.

Comment: @Stephan it seems painful because it is painful. SRP applies to regular expressions, too.

Comment: SRP?? meaning ? Something is bad because it is bad has never been an argument !

Comment: @Stephan: SRP = "Single Responsibility Principle"

Comment: The reason it is done all in one is there may be any number of formats, say 30+. So a pattern can be assigned to an incoming email account, the receiving function just matches the email against the pattern it has been given for that account. To break it down into lots of steps would mean adding a lot of extra code for each mapping, at the moment a new pattern can just be added to a config file against an email account

Comment: @JimmySavile a lot of extra code, but a lot less headache. More lines of code does not always mean more complex or harder to maintain.

Comment: @Rex M it's much easier to edit and save a config file than recompile source code file.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a suggestion but did you try to use compiled Regex ? 
Here's some information : http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Regular_Expression_Recipes%E2%80%94Compiling_Regular_Expressions

Comment: I did try this after your suggestion but it didn't make any difference as it still needs to run the regular expression once to begin with and it was just performing way too badly. Thanks